# No mapping found for HTTP request with URI - No dispatcherservlet / servletmapping error

Tags: spring-mvc, jsp

I know this is a common question but I'm getting desesperated here, Im pretty newbie and have been stuck with this for a long time now... I know this is not a DispatcherServlet or Servlet Mapping error as I'm working on a really big project that has everything working already.

What I need to do is add a form on an already existing jsp page, here is what I have

CONTROLLER:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/messaging")
public class MessagingController {


    @GetMapping
    public String messagingView(Principal principal, Model model) throws ServiceException {
            model.addAttribute("messagingInformation", new MessagingInformation());
        
        return foo; -> this returns me to the main jsp where I'm creating the form
    }
    
    @PostMapping(value = "/submitInformation") -> I've also tried with @RequestMapping(value = "/submitInformation", method = RequestMethod.POST)
      public String submitInformation(@ModelAttribute(value = "messagingInformation") @Valid MessagingInformation messagingInformation) {
        return "redirect:/messaging"; -> shouldn't this redirect me to the main jsp?
      }

}
```

JSP:

```
<form:form action="messaging/submitInformation" modelAttribute="messagingInformation" method="POST">

            <div class="row col-sm-12 margin-top-container">
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <span class="titles-select-box uppercase-text">RECEIVER</span>
                    <input name="receiver" type="email" id="receiverId" name="receiverName"
                        placeholder="Receiver" multiple>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-12 no-padding-left">
                <div class="button-container pull-right">
                    <input type="submit" value="Send" class="btn btn-default"
                        id="sendButton" />
                </div>
            </div>

        </form:form>
```

I'm mainly getting --No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/foo/messaging/submitInformation]  in DispatcherServlet -- I've asked around and I shouldn't add nothing to any cofiguration file or anything, clearly it's something wrong on my side but I can't see it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Leaving this in case anyone finds out... I was requiered to do a manual build so the java changes would show up. This is done through Projects -> Build All